# remove compile messages from clojure build failure backtraces

Tags: clojure

I would just love a way to filter out the back-traces from the compilation process and see only the messages from the running of my program.
I'm currently using La Clojure for Intellij, though I also use slime/emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to drop back to the terminal to run, you can use mmcgrana's [clj-backtrace](http://github.com/mmcgrana/clj-stacktrace) to colorize and format the output of clojure's stacktraces.

A `clj`-like script that integrates clj-backtrace is available [here](http://gist.github.com/237162).

Example:

[example of clj-backtrace http://img.skitch.com/20091117-re5bqm6f5axg25mxpwcbcx53f8.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091117-re5bqm6f5axg25mxpwcbcx53f8.png)

---

Comment: That's what I've been unknowingly looking for for some time!